# Is there a difference between the two sets of QGIS terrain analysis tools?

Tags: qgis, dem, terrain

Is there a difference between `Raster/Terrain Anaylsis` and the same features in `Raster/Analysis/DEM (Terrain Analysis)`? The two appear to do the same types of computations; are they the same or is there a difference and if so, what?

Comment: A DEM is a raster, in Esri a Terrain is a terrain http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005v00000002000000. Raster needs Spatial Analyst, Terrain needs 3D analyst. Is there a specific tool that you want to know the difference in?

Comment: Sorry, I am learning QGIS and noticed that there is a Raster/Terrain Analysis menu item and also a Raster/Analysis/DEM (Terrain Analysis) menu item.  The question is directed at QGIS users.

Comment: Perhaps you should include a QGIS tag on your question. I'm not sure about those tools, I haven't had a chance to experiment with them yet.

Comment: When you have fewer words in the body than are in the title, it's time for a rewrite.

Comment: This [answer](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353) to a GIS Meta question describes how questions here can be structured.

Comment: The menu Raster/Analysis/DEM (Terrain Analysis) uses GDAL (per Help button) and seems to be a default option.  

The menu Raster/Terrain Analysis is likely an installed plug-in, and uses a different library.  Check Plugins/Installed to verify.

Answer (score 1):

The `Raster -> Terrain Analysis` menu entry is from the core `Raster Terrain Analysis plugin`, which is installed by default. You can deactivate it in the plugin installer. It is described here:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_raster_terrain.html

and a short tutorial is here:

http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/qgis_plugins/plugin_examples.html#basic-fa-the-raster-terrain-analysis-plugin

The `Raster -> Analysis` menu entries are from gdal tools, and can be expanded by using the command line options that are available. See the GDAL manpages for details.

A tutorial can be found here:

http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/rasters/terrain_analysis.html

In addition, the processing toolbox offers the GDAL tools too, and GRASS and SAGA routines for slope and hillshading.

So plenty of possibilities to get the style you want.